# GitLab clone issue 500 over https

Tags: git, https, ldap, gitlab, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repository from gitlab for which I have master access privileges. But, I get the following error when cloning using https clone url

```
$ git clone https://username@repos.group.university.de/teammate/myrepo.git
```

> remote: Internal server error
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://username@repos.group.university.de/teammate/myrepo.git': The requested URL returned error: 500

Any clues about the issue?

Comment: Does it work with ssh?

Comment: @Justas No. I'm still facing the issue. But, what's the problem in cloning using https ?

Comment: Did you check Gitlab logs with: sudo gitlab-ctl tail or sudo less /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log ?

Comment: @Justas I'm, as a client user, just trying to clone a repository. Why should I have Gitlab installed on my machine? I don't understand the issue :(

Comment: That's server error so you should ask admin.

Comment: @Justas will do, thanks!!

Answer (score -2):

When you are not the serveradmin then you should contact the serveradmin as what you describe is a server issue. HTTP error 500 is not fixable by you as a user of the service.

The exact reasons for the issue are various and depend on the Gitlab-version, the environment and the specific setup. But they are **not** fixable by you as a user.